# Игнорируются буквы при поиске в строке

Tags: python, строки

Всех приветствую. Есть такой кусок кода:

```
import random

ALL_SYMBOLS = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'

key = list(ALL_SYMBOLS)
random.shuffle(key)
key = ''.join(key)



message = 'Абрикосовый сок после - это лучшее, что может быть'
secret_message = ''


for letter in message: 
    if key.find(letter): 
        new_index = key.find(letter)
        secret_message += ALL_SYMBOLS[new_index]
    else: 
        print(f'Не нашёл символ - {letter}')
        secret_message += letter

print(secret_message)
```

Пытаюсь зашифровать `message` простым подстановочным шифром. На данном этапе пробелы игнорирую и ожидаю, что в зашифрованном сообщении они останутся на том же месте, что и в исходном сообщении. Всё шифруется вроде бы хорошо, но иногда проскакивает

```
Не нашёл символ - ь
зщЁгСЫЭЫфЦьяЭЫСяэЫЭцПяяяпжЫяцШЧЮППяяЧжЫяъЫчПжящЦжь
```

В данном случае пробелы заменились на символ "я" и почему-то не найден ь. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Начнем с того, что `key.find(letter)` почти всегда возвращает True. В случае ненахождения эта функция вернет не 0, а -1, что есть True. А если `key.find() == 0`, то, естественно, вылетает "не нашел".

Comment: И вообще, задачу можно легко решить в одну строку. Почитайте про функцию `translate`.  Валидацию нашел/не нашел лучше осуществлять перед зашифровкой и для понятности, и для скорости.

Comment: А "иногда проскакивает" - как раз когда возвращается индекс 0, т.е. когда буква оказывается первой в key.

Comment: @Глеб точно. Проглядел. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key.find(letter)` возвращает **index** `key` и **-1** если не находит. Соответственно измените код на:

```
import random

ALL_SYMBOLS = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'

key = list(ALL_SYMBOLS)
random.shuffle(key)
key = ''.join(key)


message = 'Абрикосовый сок после - это лучшее, что может быть'
secret_message = ''


for letter in message: 
    if key.find(letter) != -1: 
        new_index = key.find(letter)
        secret_message += ALL_SYMBOLS[new_index]
    else: 
        print(f'Не нашёл символ - {letter}')
        secret_message += letter

print(secret_message)
```

Comment: Да, а еще лучше — `letter in key`. И яснее, и быстрее.

Comment: Да, я тоже об этом думал). Решил оставить так, чтобы человек увидел ошибку в данном способе у себя